# google appscript HTML button issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am working on a sidebar action in google appscript and i am doing dynamic menus for the first time.  I am having issues with the button submission:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="loadCommentForm()">Add Comment</button>
    <button onclick="google.script.host.close()">Close Sidebar</button>
    <div id="formContainer"></div>

    <script>
      function loadCommentForm() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showForm).getValuesFromSolutions();
      }

      function showForm(data) {
          var formHtml = `
              <h2>Add Comment</h2>

                  <form id="form1">
                      Reference Section: ${data.referenceSection}<br>
                      Solution: ${data.solution}<br>
                      Comment: <br>
                      <textarea name="formComment" id="comment" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea><br>
                      <button onclick="submitComment('${data.referenceSection}', '${data.solution}')">Submit</button>
                  </form>
          `;
          document.getElementById('formContainer').innerHTML = formHtml;
      }


      function submitComment(referenceSection, solution) {
        var comment = document.getElementById('comment').value;

        google.script.run.appendToAssumptions(comment, referenceSection, solution)
          .withFailureHandler(showError);

        // Clear the formContainer and show the main menu
        var mainMenuHtml = `
            <button onclick="loadCommentForm()">Add Comment</button>
            <button onclick="google.script.host.close()">Close Sidebar</button>
        `;
        document.getElementById('formContainer').innerHTML = mainMenuHtml;
      }


      function showError(error){
          console.log("ERROR: " + error.message);
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My sidebar loads great and when click on my first menu to "Add Comment" that works great.  Once the new form loads I pull in my data successfully and I have my text area to enter my comment but when i click submit comment nothing happens.  I feel the syntax is right and that the issue is inside my form 1 with the button actually executing the issue.  Sadly i am terrible at debugging HTML inside google appscript.  Any advice here would be helpful.

APPENDING FUNCTION PER COMMUNITY REQUEST:
This is located in my 'sidebar/appscript.gs' file.

```
function appendToAssumptions(comment, referenceSection, solution) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('targetsheet');
  sheet.appendRow([comment, referenceSection, solution]);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the execution log?  Do you see `appendToAssumptions` in the log?

Comment: Execution log is empty with nothing, and the appenToAssumptions is in a .gs file which i have validated and tested that it works.  I am adding the function to my previous post so you can see it.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible because getValuesFromSolution() is not defined.  Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I believe `appendToAssumptions` does not return anything for chaining where as `.withFailureHandler` does.

Try changing this:

```
google.script.run.appendToAssumptions(comment, referenceSection, solution)
          .withFailureHandler(showError);
```

To this:

```
google.script.run.withFailureHandler(showError).appendToAssumptions(comment, referenceSection, solution);
```

Here is my copy of your project

[image]

Execution log

```
Head    appendToAssumptions Unknown Aug 19, 2023, 9:46:23 AM    0.443 s 
Completed
Cloud logs
Aug 19, 2023, 9:46:24 AM    Info    hello
Aug 19, 2023, 9:46:24 AM    Info    Reference
Aug 19, 2023, 9:46:24 AM    Info    Solution
```

Comment: Made the change and see no errors in the execution log.

Comment: I copied your project and made the change and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

@TheWizEd thank you for your feedback.  I welcome a link to a tutorial on working with the execution log.  With that said, my code was fine to your point; what I left out from the post was the data being passed in.  While I was troubleshooting, I came across a video on youtube that showed me how to inspect the element and look for HTML errors via the browser.  In the HTML I noticed that the Button value being returned had spacing issues and a hard return within the input type, see below.

```
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitComment('Business Requirements &amp; Considerations 

Section code: BRC', 'Solution 1 w/Link')">
```

To address this, I made the following changes:

**the showForm function:**

```
  function showForm(data) {
      var formHtml = `
          <h2>Add Comment</h2>
          <form id="form1">
              Reference Section: ${data.referenceSection}<br>
              Solution: ${data.solution}<br>
              Comment: <br>
              <textarea name="formComment" id="comment" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea><br>
              <input type="button" value="Submit" 
                    data-reference="${data.referenceSection}" 
                    data-solution="${data.solution}" 
                    onclick="submitCommentFromButton(this)">
          </form>
      `;
      document.getElementById('formContainer').innerHTML = formHtml;
  }
```

I googled around, and this captures data and handles values being passed in.
I then created a new function that handles these characters without causing issues.

```
  function submitCommentFromButton(buttonElement) {
      var referenceSection = buttonElement.getAttribute('data-reference');
      var solution = buttonElement.getAttribute('data-solution');
      submitComment(referenceSection, solution);
  }
```

So in closing the function worked with simple characters but with complex values being passed in I broke the HTML